# Switching Mode Power Supply Fluctuating Output

Tags: power-supply, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, switching, testing

I designed a switching mode power supply using LNK-562, I share the circuit schematic below.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/q7GMugS.png]

Note that NTC, fuse, and the input filter inductor is replaced with shorts in the real circuits.

I am testing the circuit in varying conditions and I noticed that the circuit fails  to keep the output voltage the same for every condition. For example, if I use 100 Ohms as the load, the output is 3V.  For the case of an output load of 220 Ohms, I get 5V (which is the intended voltage). Eventually, the voltage converges to 8V with no load condition. The circuit should be able to handle an output power of 1.5W. So, I understand that the circuit will fail to keep the voltage at 5V in the no load case, however, a small variation of changing the resistor to 220 to 100 should not change the output figures that much. Given the power requirement, I should be able to connect a 20 Ohm resistor.

I tested every node of the circuit. Bias circuit seems to be working fine. The LNK562 operates by keeping the voltage at TP1 constant. Namely, it should be 1.69V for all cases of loads and this is verified by an oscilloscope measurement.

Note that the fluctuations in the output voltage are kept at minimum. For the case of 5V output, the ripple is measured to be 12mV which is a very good figure considering that this is a student project and by no means it is designed for commercial market.

What do you suggest I do? Which nodes I should check and what kind of waveform might be an indication of a problem? How do you define the problem I have?

The circuit is now being tested at 110V RMS. Also, I am a senior EEE student. Also note that the circuit is printed and verified by the professor.

Comment: Doesn't N2 belong on the secondary side with N3?

Comment: It is the bias-feedback part of the circuit and is not isolated, hence the placement.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Just an observation, but you are using a half-wave power supply, instead of a full-wave bridge rectifier. That cuts your available power in half to begin with.

Comment: @Sparky256, the LNK562 can not handle more than 2W. The use of a full wave rectifier would be an overkill and the use of a half bridge is recommended by the vendor.

Comment: Also that 1N4007 diode should be a UF1N4007. It needs to be a ultra-fast rectifier, not a common AC rectifier.

Comment: Actually, the diodes are specifically chosen to be slow so that they would also rectify the signal. All of the components are chosen accordingly with the datasheet and application notes provided by the vendor of the LNK562.

Comment: show the tp1 waveform

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I checked it and today I had the opportunity of consulting to my professor and it is revealed that voltage at tp1 is way more noisy than it should be. Now that I know the problem, I started working on fixing the pcb. Added an additional capacitor, changed nothing. The professor worried that it might be due to inductance of the ground lines. To eliminate that, I also added a piece of wire directly connecting the negative side of the capacitor to the ground. This did not have any impact, too. I don't know what else I can do. Thank you so much for pointing out the error, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regulation of that configuration can be poor, as it depends on a tight coupling between N2 and N3 and how closely does the voltage on C3 follows the voltage of the changing load. Given the 36k & 1uF load on that feedback circuit it is likely to be too slow to respond to load changes, and too sensitive to initial transients on the transformer coils.

You can try by reducing the 33k resistor and/or 1uF capacitor. And/or adding a load directly to N3 to reduce the influence of the switching transients.